# Am I missing something, when filtering this observable collection?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a routine which parses data from an xml feed.

```
    ...

    matches.Add(_item);
}
```

And shortly after this I want to only include the items which match my where clause

```
if (this.MatchType == FixtureType.Played)
{
    matches = matches.ToList().Where(
        m =>
            m.matchResult == "D"
    ).ToObservableCollection();
}
```

after this if I put a breakpoint on, I notice that *matches* now contains the items I am looking for.

The problem now is that the control that is databound to the observablecollection still has the preliminary data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that there are 2 `ObservableCollection` instances in this scenario

- The original one which the control is bound to
- The new one you created with the `ToObservableCollection` call

In order to get the new results to display in the Control you need to rebind it to the new `ObservableCollection` instance.  That or modify the original instance inline.

```
var results = matches.Where(m => m.matchResult == "D").ToList();
matches.Clear();
foreach (var cur in results) {
  matches.Add(cur);
}
```

Comment: @HiTechMagic yes that is a valid solution. Really though it's usually best to expose collections as readonly properties to avoid the problem entirely.

Answer (score 1):

That is because your control reefers to the old instance of `matches`, you are creating a new observable collection and assigning that to `matches`, but your control is not bound to the `matches` variable, but to the value `matches` had when it was bound. You should instead modify matches and remove all those items not matching your condition.

Answer (score 0):

I would ask why are you having a programmatic variable to Bind to.

Using an MVVM framework such as MVVM Light sorts out these kinds of scenarios very nicely.

Just have a property in the view model and bind you view to that, when ever you then update the view model the page will be automatically updated, simples.

There are many examples of this, including the databound template in the DEV tools (which implements basic notifypropertychanged behaviours) a better way is to upscale to MVVM light (http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com) or further with the likes of Calburn.Micro (http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/)

Comment: i need to upgrade my project to mvvmlight in order to understand it correctly.